# Comma index in python list bracket

Tags: python

example is below. What is this? A comma is in the python list-bracket. How can I understand this?

`id(x[i,j]) == id(x[i][j])` shows True.

So, `x[i,j]` is always same at `x[i][j]`?

or, `x[i,j]` is actually same as `x[(i,j)]`? index is tuple.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random((64,3,32,10))
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        print(x[i,j])
```

======
 I guess 
this is numpy's special implementation. Numpy overwrites "_getitem__" function for using tuple index.

I tried it for
1) basic python
2) overwrite "_getitem__ " and
3) basic numpy.

1) shows error. "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"
2) has....no problem if I implemented right.
3) just works well.

So, I guess numpy developers did implemented their "*getitem*" function for tuple, and it works same arr[x,y,z] == arr[x][y][z].

Comment: That is an indexing operation. `x[i, j]` -> `x.__getitem__((i, j))` "x[i,j] is alway same at x[i][j]?" No, not necessarily.

Comment: Dont base conclusions off of [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) It is a method to check if two references point to the same object. In case of numpy, where the core arrays are "outsourced" to C, the python just has a reference which stays true for all indices.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh "the python just has a reference which stays true for all indices" huh?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: That's not how the ID values or the references work. What's going on is that the lifetimes of the wrapper objects are non-overlapping, so Python is free to reuse the memory. (In this particular case, the wrapper objects are derived from the same array cell and contain the same value, but that turns out to have no effect at all on how things work out.)

Comment: [If you keep the wrapper objects alive](https://ideone.com/7ItVIK), the allocator can't reuse the same memory, and you end up with different ID values.

Comment: i did not know that, thanks a lot. @user2357112 til, im dumb. Why does the first one not "stay" alive so to speak?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh because as soon as you pass it to `id` it no longer exists (after `id` terminates) so it is *immediately* reclaimed (ref-count goes to 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Numpy special ability.
[Numpy official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html)
"Unlike lists and tuples, numpy arrays support multidimensional indexing for multidimensional arrays. That means that it is not necessary to separate each dimension’s index into its own set of square brackets."

```
>>> x.shape = (2,5) # now x is 2-dimensional
>>> x[1,3]
8
>>> x[1,-1]
9
```

Answer (score 4):

While numpy behaves the same way with the two, they are technically different.

You can see the difference by implementing `__getitem__` yourself:

```
class GetitemTest(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print("getting: %r" %(item, ))
        return self
```

Then:

```
>>> x = GetitemTest()
>>> x[1,2]
getting: (1, 2)
<__main__.GetitemTest object at 0x10bb6d810>

>>> x[1][2]
getting: 1
getting: 2
<__main__.GetitemTest object at 0x10bb6d810>
```

Notice that `x[1,2]` only calls `__getitem__` once, but `x[1][2]` calls it twice.

Comment: So, tuple list-index only allowed when it(gettiem fun) overwrite or re-implement for using tuple index?

Comment: from your answer, I find reference document. [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html). "Unlike lists and tuples, numpy arrays support multidimensional indexing for multidimensional arrays. That means that it is not necessary to separate each dimension’s index into its own set of square brackets." thank you.